# How to define distance between two functions in a non-linear space (example of non-linear space: shape space)?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, parametric

Suppose I have two parametric circle $f_1=(acost,asint)$ and $f_2=(bcos t,bsint)$, $t\in(0,2\pi),a>0,b>0$, which lies in some non-linear space.          Are there any way, how to define the distance between these two functions?
I am thinking to define a function $f=f_1-f_2$, (component wise difference), and will take norm = $(\int_0^{2\pi}|f_1(t)-f_2(t)|^2 dt)^\frac{1}{2}$, as the distance between above two function. Is there any fault? Please suggest.

Comment: If $a$ is not equals to $b$ then $f_1$ is different from $f_2$. I am concern about the shape of this type of closed curves, which I think a lies in some non-linear space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid distance definition, between two vector functions defined on the same domain.

If you want to measure the distance between two curves (shapes), this may not be a very good choice, as it will depend on the parameterization of the curves. You can consider the [Hausdorff distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) instead.

NB: one could try to make the first approach parameterization-independent by using the intrinsic equation based on the arc length, but for closed curves that still makes it dependent on the starting points.

Comment: Thanks @Yves Daoust. Suppose I take the fractional arc length parametrization of each functions (which are some standardised and doamin of these functions are same). And now we try to find the distance between the two new standardised functions, then how to proceed?

Comment: What is your purpose ?

Comment: I have planar contours in $\mathbb{R^2}$. I want to  define a distance measure between two contours in this space.

Comment: Then the distance must be parameterization independent. Use the Hausdorff or the chamfer distance. (Unfortunately, I couldn't find a good link for the latter.)

Comment: It's ok. Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

The $L^p$ ($1\le p<\infty$) distance:
$$\left(\int_0^{2\pi}|f_1(t)-f_2(t)|^p dt\right)^\frac{1}{p}$$
The $\sup$ or $L^\infty$ distance:
$$\sup_{t\in[0,2\pi]}|f_1(t)-f_2(t)|$$
The "weird" $L^p$ ($0<p<1$) distance:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}|f_1(t)-f_2(t)|^p dt$$
Depending of the space (set of functions) considered, this distances will have good or bad properties. The $\sup$ distange is good if you want continuous functions.

Comment: Thanks for the correct definition